# Subtract one object from another one with in array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to know the efficient way to subtract two object key[amount] values based on the action key.

```
data = [
  { _id: { token: 'BEEF', action: 'received' }, amount: 4 },
  { _id: { token: 'BEEF', action: 'sent' }, amount: 2 },
  { _id: { token: 'GFUN', action: 'received' }, amount: 9},
  { _id: { token: 'HOT', action: 'received' }, amount: 6 },
  { _id: { token: 'HOT', action: 'sent' }, amount: 4 },
  { _id: { token: 'LINK', action: 'received' }, amount: 8},
  { _id: { token: 'METM', action: 'sent' }, amount: 7 },
  { _id: { token: 'METM', action: 'received' }, amount: 9},
  { _id: { token: 'ORTC', action: 'received' }, amount: 5},
  { _id: { token: 'ORTC', action: 'sent' }, amount: 3 }
]
```

desired result after calculation

```
[
  { token: 'BEEF', amount: 2 },
  { token: 'GFUN', amount: 9},
  { token: 'HOT' , amount: 2 },
  { token: 'LINK', amount: 8},
  { token: 'METM', amount: 2 },
  { token: 'ORTC', amount: 2},
]
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: By "efficient" are you referring to performance? Selected answer is less performant than the other.

Comment: @JBallin yeah I was not necessarily thinking about “efficient” when I wrote my answer.  I think my answer is more readable and understandable, but it is also less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```js
const results = [];
const idx = {};
data.forEach(v => {
  const token = v['_id']['token'];
  if(!token in idx) {
    const item = {
      token: token,
      amount: 0
    };
    results.push(item);
    idx[token] = item;
  }
  idx[token].amount += 
    v['_id']['action'] == 'received' ? v.amount : -v.amount;
});
```

`results` is the final array. `idx` is a lookup into the array in order to make locating the correct item easier.

Comment: This is more efficient, given that it only goes through the array once. Nice use of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of ways to approach this, but here's what I did.

First break the array into two arrays, one for the `sent` items and one for the `received`.

```
const sent = data.filter(o => o._id.action === 'sent');

const recieved = data.filter(o => o._id.action === 'received');
```

I'm assuming that there is always an entry in `received` and there may or may not be an entry in `sent`.  So I mapped from the `recieved` array to the results.  For each entry, I find the corresponding entry in `sent`, and if there is no matching entry, I subtract `0`.

```
const differences = recieved.map( r => {
    const s = sent.find(o => o._id.token === r._id.token );
    const sentAmount = s ? s.amount : 0;
    return { 
        token: r._id.token,
        amount: r.amount - sentAmount,
    }
})
```